# Updating dependent form content using AJAX...passing form variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jquery

How can I pass a form variable to a template that is only used by AJAX to load dynamic data into a section of a form?

I have a Course form that belongs_to a lesson, and a lesson has_many gradable_items.  If the lesson select input is changed...the nested fields for the gradable_items must update to reflect the chosen lesson.

```
  jQuery ->
    l = $("#course_lesson_id")
    l.on "change", ->
      $("#gradable_items_container").load("gradable_items_inputs?lesson=#{l.val()}")
```

The above scripts works.  It loads the code in gradable_items_inputs.html.erb into the target div.

## gradable_items_inputs.html.erb

GradedItem is the model where the grades for each GradableItem are stored.  A GradedItem belongs_to :gradable_item and belongs_to the lesson.

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :graded_items do |graded_item| %>
    <%= gradable_item.name %>
    <%= graded_item.input :gradable_item_id, input_html: { value: gradable_item.id } %>
  <% end %>
```

When I put the above code into the gradable_items_inputs.html.erb file, I get 'undefined local variable "f"' error.  I tried moving the f.simple_fields_for call outside of AJAX template file...but, then I get the same error, but for the graded_item variable.  One way or another I need to pass that form variable to the template via javascript.

This is an overview of what my code looks like:

```
parent form do |f|
   f.association :lesson

  nested_form do |n|
    // the fields that go here are dependent on the lesson that is chosen above.  A model called  LessonGradableItem is a join model that holds what items a particular lesson should be graded against.  I generate an input for each item...then save the result in the GradedItem model.
    // since these inputs are loaded via AJAX from an external template, the form is being broken...how can I pass the n form variable to that file?
  end  

end
```

I tried passing the form variable as a data param and a url param, but it get interpreted in the gradable_items_inputs.html.erb file as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the form variable.  Construct the nested form separately.  So, create a new Object.new in your action, so that the nested form (in a case similar to mine) doesn't need to know the parent form object.  To make this work, I also had to set the id: and name: so that the inputs were given the correct structure.

Comment: Downside of the above is the original object sent to the form will not be the one returned if there are errors.  So, if the form is redirected and the page reloads...it won't have any data of what failed.